# clicar na div aumentar clicar novamente diminuir

Tags: javascript, html, css

Pessoal se puderem me ajude nessa questão gostaria de clicar em uma div que esta fixa no rodape e ela aumentar e depois clicar novamente e ela diminuir, como faço isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você deveria incluir um pouco do código do que você tentou fazer, mas aqui está um exemplo bem simples pra te dar pelo menos uma ideia de como começar:

HTML:

```
<div id="div"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var big = true;

$('#div').click(function() {
  if(big) {
    big = false;
    $(this).css('height', '50px');
    $(this).css('width', '50px');
  } else {
    big = true;
    $(this).css('height', '100px');
    $(this).css('width', '100px');
  }


});
```

Javascript utilizando Animação:

```
var big = true;

$('#div').click(function() {
  if(big) {
    big = false;
    $(this).animate({
      height : "50px",
      width : "50px"
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    big = true;
    $(this).animate({
      height : "100px",
      width : "100px"
    }, 1000);
  }


});
```

Pra ver ao vivo: https://codepen.io/leofontes/pen/bBrVbZ

Como eu disse, bem simples, pra te ajudar como iniciante.

Comment: é isso mesmo cara muito obrigado

Comment: man como faço isso em uma div fixa na parte inferior da tela?